# How is possible in React changing component Icon look on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component Button and inside the button, I have a component Icon, I was trying by useState but It does not affect at all the state in the parent component. I have a main component Header where I have title and component Icon, which I won't change depending on which button will be clicked. For example, If I click the button with the home Icon - the next Header title icon will change to Home if the cloud will change to cloud etc.

Header.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Button from 'components/Button';

const Header = (props) => {
return(
<div>
<h4 className="title">
              <Icon name={props.titleIcon}/>
            Title
            </h4>
<div>
);
};
```

Button.js

```
    import React,{useState} from 'react';
    import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
    import { Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react';
    
    const Button = (props) => {
    const [icon, setIcon] = useState('home')
    
    const handleClick = ()
     => {
    setIcon(props.titleIcon = props.icon)
    };
    return(
     <div>
          <Button>
            <a href={props.link} target="_blank">
              <Icon name={props.icon}/>
    {props.name}
            </a>
          </Button>
        </div>
    );
    
    };
```

How I can achieve this effect of changing icons?

Greetings

Comment: use Context to share data between components

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is quite a bit wrong with this one:

1. you havent actually used the handleClick function
2. the setIcon function parameter was used as an assignment. The actual value was not used

The correct code might look something like this:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const Button = ({titleIcon, name, link}) => {
  const [icon, setIcon] = useState('home')

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIcon(titleIcon)
  };
  return(
      <div>
            <Button onClick={handleClick}>
              <a href={link} target="_blank">
                <Icon name={icon}/>
                  {name}
              </a>
        </Button>
      </div>
  );

};
```